# Error running grunt/starting server.js

Tags: node.js, error-handling, gruntjs, server, mean-stack

For some quick background, I am following a MEANio tutorial found [here](http://learn.mean.io/). Now, I am at the part where I have run mean init, it has finished, and then cd into the project directory and run

```
npm install
```

After fixing  a brief JSON syntax issue inside package.json (the end of the file was slightly mis-typed), I attempted to run

```
grunt
```

Hook task, clean, jshint, and csslint all ran fine, and then when I get to the portion of the build script that runs

```
node --debug server.js
```

I run into errors

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL
    at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1024:19)
    at listen (net.js:1065:10)
    at net.js:1147:9
    at asyncCallback (dns.js:68:16)
    at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:121:9)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I am pretty clueless about the inner workings of Node, does anyone know what this error refers to? I followed the MEANio tutorial nearly exactly, with the exception of where my node is at, I just have it in a folder that I have added to my $PATH in my .bashrc file. Could someone give me some advice on what files to check/debug?

Comment: can't help you, but consider moving to mean.js, it is less problematic

Comment: Yea @Mike, mean.js I was able to get working. Good call.

Answer (score 0):

The `EADDRNOTAVAIL` error typically occurs when you are trying to run a server on a port that is already in use. That tutorial suggests that the port would be `3000` (which is a typical default for Node applications). You should check to see that you do not have anything else running on port `3000` already.